# Using Javascript mutation observer function, how can I access the JavaScript functions of a generated iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, video.js, mutation-observers

I have a external script which generates a local iFrame on my page.  The iframe is loading a videojs player.

I want to access the iframe and call the videojs play() function to start playing the video.

The only issue is I cant use the parent dom to access it until its loaded so I am using mutation observer function to check when its generated and loaded on the page.

Its worked successfully but I seem to not be able to access the videojs functions I simply get "cannot read property play of undefined".

```
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++)
                {
                    //console.log(mutation);
                    mutation.addedNodes[i].contentWindow.player.play();
                }
            })                    
        });
```

Comment: please check if the added node is a player instance. Otherwise your loop will crash...

Comment: It always comes back as undefined even though i know the addedNode is the iframe and inside of it should have the player object.  In fact, if I wait for the page to load and use console I can directly access the iframe and play the video

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by waiting for the iframe to load:

```
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
            mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++)
                {
                    mutation.addedNodes[i].contentWindow.onload = function(){
                        this.player.play();   
                    };
                }
            })                    
        });
```